# Get Shortcode Content As Is

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode

```
[my_shortcode param1="Parameter 1"]The content here adds 
br tag here and converts my quotes 'like this' to html
but does not touch double quotes "somehow"[/my_shortcode]
```

I would like to get the content of my shortcode as is, without br tags, p tags and html entity converted single quotes or some other surprises.

Is there a way to get the shortcode content as is?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want the parsed shortcode:

```
$content = do_shortcode('[my_shortcode]foobar[/my_shortcode]');
```

To get the content "as is" you would need to reverse engineer how WordPress does the conversions. Usually for WYSIWYG content WordPress runs the content through a few functions: `wpautop` and `wp_texturize`. `wpautop` adds p-tags and `wp_texturize` does general cleanups and character conversions.

Take a look at those functions and see how you could reverse the things they do. One would be to just use `strip_tags()` and `html_entity_decode()` for the smallest effort.